# Do rules for Magewrights exist in an unearthed arcana article?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, eberron

I have been listening to Keith Baker on an episode of Todd Talks, where he discusses magewrights.

Unless I'm mistaken, he mentioned that the rules for magewrights exist outside of the core Eberron book, possibly in an unearthed arcana.

As I'm interested in using magewrights outside of Eberron, I would like to know if the rules are in an unearthed arcana before deciding if I want to purchase the actual book.

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. The crux of my question is whether you are aware of what is presented in the official books and find it insufficient or you are not aware of that (as suggested by you pondering to buy them).

Comment: @szega I'm not aware of any rules.

Comment: What do you intent to use magewrights for?

Comment: @gcl mundane magic workers, either in the Ravnica or Theros campaign settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Magewrights do not appear in any UA article

Ok, showing a negative is hard, but to my knowledge (and search) it is not part of a UA article. The overwelming majority of UA content is PC options (class, subclass, or races) with a few exceptions. These exceptions (magic items of eberron, ships and sea, mass combat) are generally also rule sets which need playtesting, which Magewrights mostly aren't.

Magewrights were included in a playtesting document though; *Wayfinder's Guide to Eberron* (a "living document" meaning it acted like a digital book, but received updates). There is a section on how [magewrights exist in the world](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/wgte/welcome-to-khorvaire-everyday-life#Magewrights).

The [section in E:RftLW is less detailed](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/erftlw/welcome-to-eberron#AMagicalWorld), but it also contains an [NPC section](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/erftlw/friends-and-foes#Magewright) for when you need to give them a stat block (contains much of the same information as the WGtE section).